# What is "colorspace" in imagedata?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, getimagedata, putimagedata

Needed to do some pixel manipulation, but `ImageData` has changed. Now it has a `colorSpace` property.

What is this, and how do I use it as normal?

Just get an `ImageData` object in Chrome to reproduce.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This comes from [this proposal](https://github.com/WICG/canvas-color-space/blob/master/CanvasColorSpaceProposal.md) to implement color-space management in canvas.

Currently, canvas is stuck with `legacy-srgb` 8 bit depth. Some monitor can't handle this low level of information.

This is still a proposal, but the currently proposed syntax to set the colorSpace of a 2DContext would be `ctx.getContext('2d', {colorSpace: 'color-space', pixelFormat: 'pixelFormat', linearPixelMath: boolean});`

Currently, no one has implemented it yet, but chromium and chrome are in the process of doing so.
Their current implementation only exposes a getter `colorSpace` property on ImageData objects, and a `getContextAttributes` method on the Context2D object, but there is not yet a way to set it for us (maybe there is with some startup flag, but I didn't find it).

**Note:** You need to set the `Experimental canvas features` flag to true in `chrome://flags` to get access to these properties.

But anyway, this property should in no way alter your code. All the default parameters of the ImageData are still the same.

Comment: This is now possible in Chrome (and soon in Firefox and Safari). Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69274917/8583692).