# How to specify color space for canvas in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, color-space

What is the default color space used in JS canvas?

How can I change the color space used for rendering an HTML canvas element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting in [Chrome version 94](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule) (and also [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1703654) and [Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=225140)), when creating a canvas 2d object, you can now provide an [options object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3089561/8583692) argument specifying your desired color space to use (`"srgb"` or `"display-p3"`):

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let options = { colorSpace: "display-p3" };
const context = canvas.getContext("2d", options);
```

Also, note that the **default** color space used for canvas elements is now officially (rather than conventionally and implicitly) **sRGB** (`"srgb"`).

You can watch the Chrome [YouTube announcement](https://youtu.be/c5XIDt90VgY?t=28) and read its [feature specification](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5807007661555712).

Related links:

- Canvas color space [proposal on GitHub](https://github.com/WICG/canvas-color-space/blob/main/CanvasColorSpaceProposal.md)
- HTML [color space specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#colour-spaces-and-colour-correction)

<sub>Thanks to isherwood and Kaiido for their comments.</sub>

Comment: A front-end developer should [never link "here"](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/)

Comment: Specifications are at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#colour-spaces-and-colour-correction